# 'for' loop in array push (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, shopify

I have a syntax problem, I am trying to integrate go.pl analytics to cart in shopify so the final code will look like this:

```js
var goadservicesq = goadservicesq || [];
goadservicesq.push(
  [
    "_BASKET",
    [
      // first position in basket
      {
        identifier: '35353635535',
        quantity: '2'
      },
      // second position in basket
      {
        identifier: '55353533378566',
        quantity: '1'
      },
      // last position in basket
      {
        identifier: '458457435643464',
        quantity: '3'
      },
      // extra product which solves the "comma" problem 
      {}
    ]
  ]
);
```

and here I am trying to make "for" loop inside to have a final result like above:

```js
// trying to make "for" loop
$.getJSON( "/cart.js", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
  
  // user.go.pl CART script
  var goadservicesq = goadservicesq || [];
  goadservicesq.push(
    [
      "_BASKET",
      [
                      
        for (var i = 0; i < data.items_count; i++) {  
          {
            identifier: data.items[i].id,
            quantity: data.items[i].quantity
          }, 
        } 
              
        // extra product which solves the "comma" problem 
        {}
      ]
    ]
  );
});
```

it throws an error -> http://prntscr.com/ci7jpz
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build up the basket array outside of the literal array:

```
// trying to make "for" loop
$.getJSON( "/cart.js", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    // user.go.pl CART script
    var basket = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items_count; i++) {
        basket.push({
            identifier: data.items[i].id,
            quantity: data.items[i].quantity
        });
    }
    var goadservicesq = goadservicesq || [];
    goadservicesq.push( [ "_BASKET", basket ] );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a loop in an array like that, but if `data.items` is an array you could make use of [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like that:

```
$.getJSON( "/cart.js", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);

  // user.go.pl CART script
  var goadservicesq = goadservicesq || [];
  goadservicesq.push(
    [
      "_BASKET",
      [
        data.items.map(function (item) {
          return {
            identifier: item.id,
            quantity: item.quantity
          };
        });
      ]
    ]
  );
});
```